# is there an automated, general, way to schedule sending/receiving files

Tags: ftp, monitoring

We currently have several custom (perl) processes which upload/download clients to/from clients (ftp,sftp,web,etc.). These processes send success or failure emails to various addresses. Some processes make several attempts and send warning emails after each attempt. Some scripts confirm all files from a set are available and kick of other scripts.

While the upload/download processes feel hacked together, going through the notification emails (we can get several 100 a day!!) is a chore by itself.

Is there a general solution -- open source or commercial - which does this type of work? Something which not only handles uploading/downloading files, monitoring directories, etc., but also provides a sane way of checking the status of various tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly overkill, but an ESB (Enterprise Service Bus) platform can probably do what you want.

From the Oracle ESB documentation:

> An enterprise service bus moves data among multiple endpoints, both within and outside of an enterprise.

By their nature, they are large and complex beasts but they bring a lot to the table. They generally lean towards XML, Web Services and Message Queues but have adapters for local file, FTP, and email integration.

There are many choices, free and commercial: [Comparison of business integration software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_business_integration_software)

Apologies for not being more specific but choosing an ESB platform is not a simple task. I would be keen to hear if others have more specific recommendations for your particular query.